# How to enforce touching within a ring shape using iOS SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I need to have the player moving the finger within the shaded ring:
[image]

The program should be able to detect "out of boundary" events once the finger moves outside the ring (shown in red).

Any best practices for doing this in SpriteKit, ideally in Swift? Thanks!

Comment: I am sure there is a better approach but i would use analytic geometry to check if the touch is within the ring. Actually, checking distance from center should be enough

Comment: @lukasbalaz7 Thanks, checking distance from center should work. Maybe I should ask how to do this with an irregular shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw your shapes using [CGPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html), then use [CGPathContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) to determine if the touched locations are inside or outside the path.

You can use CGPaths like this in SpriteKit using [SKShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKShapeNode/shapeNodeWithPath:).

Comment: From the doc, I think CGPathContainsPoint calculates whether a certain point is *on* the path, not *within* the shape defined by the path. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @MinosNiu No it calculates whether it is inside the shape, see the 'discussion' which says: "A point is contained in a path if it would be inside the painted region when the path is filled."